# php syntax error with if and else

Tags: php, syntax

I have the following markup.I am not able to make it work.It shows syntax error.

```
if(has_terms( array('something','else'), 'product_cat' ) ) {
   $output .= '<div class="list_image">';
   $output .= '</div>';
}else{
  $output .= '<div class="list_post">';
  $output .= '</div>';
}
endif;
```

What `syntax` error I made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `endif;` When you use curly braces you don't need (and cannot use) `endif`.

This:

```
if (true) {
  echo 'hello';
} else {
  echo 'goodbye';
}
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
if (true):
  echo 'hello';
else:
  echo 'goodbye';
endif;
```

You cannot mix the two styles.